# Passing any data from a partial view that is rendered with $.get() to ContentPage

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, parameter-passing, asp.net-mvc-partialview, viewbag

I am trying to make my web application like a desktop application. I am also **not** using any `_LayoutPage` and `@RenderBody()`.

I have a `ContentPage` as MasterPage and a tag named `main`. I am using `ajax get` method to render my views or partial views like this:

```
  $.get(url).done(function (result) {
            $("main").html(result);
        });
```

I managed to inject my `script` and `css` files with javascript functions.

And now I want to pass some specific datas without using javascript functions.

It can be via using ViewBag, I guess.

I want to pass that data from my `partialView`:

```
 ViewBag.BodyClass = "signup-page";
```

to my `MainPage` like this:

```
<body class="@ViewBag.BodyClass">
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote that code on my `partialView`. It adds a class at `ContentPage`'s body tag

```
$("body").addClass("signup-page");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a script manager ($.get) that calls your server to get the views and partial views, no problem.

When you request a URL, normally MVC calls a Controller and Action. In that action you can return content, view, partial view, file and so on...

You can create a new instance of a class model and pass to your partial view.

```
public ActionResult Index(string parameter1, string parameter2)
{
     var model = new Models.ModelTest();
     model.BodyClass = "some class";

     return PartialView("_Page", model);
}
```

You will call some like this:

```
$.get("http://localhost/app/getviews?id=3422&parameter1=test&parameter2=foo")
```

In your view or partial view:

```
@model YourApp.Models.ModelTest

<body class="@Model.BodyClass">
```

I use that all the time.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I have no problem about passing data **to** PartialView. The problem is passing data **from** PartialView to my page that i use it as Contentpage, at the same controller

Comment: you are saying that will want to "share" some data from your partial view and use in your content page right? Is that partial view is called inside that content page?

Comment: yeah of course. it is in contentpage at the runtime.